# Making text vertically centered in li and ul tags when an image is used

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center text with images when  and

bullet points are used, but I am seeing the bullet point and the text get pushed to the bottom each time (i.e. [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDBW8/)).

I have this HTML at the moment (no CSS):

```
<ul id="features-list">
<li><a href="#1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2716"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2717"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2718"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2719"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this (PNG mockup):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use vertical-align:
`a img {vertical-align:middle;}`
http://jsfiddle.net/ZDBW8/2/

Answer (score 1):

You would set [**`vertical-align:middle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) on the `img` elements:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3RMXN/)

```
#features-list li a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Link 1, Link 2..` to `<p>Link 1</p>, <p>Link 2</p> ....`

After that you will need to define the `<img>` as `float:left` and the `<p>` as `margin-top: 15px`

The margin that I have defined doesn't have any sense... you will need to check how much `px` you will need.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is no need to float elements for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="vertical-align:middle"` to you img tag.

```
 <ul id="features-list">
        <li><a href="#1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2716"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#2"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2717"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66" style="vertical-align:middle">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2718"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66" style="vertical-align:middle">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2719"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/R68A_B_train.JPG/100px-R68A_B_train.JPG" width="66" height="66" style="vertical-align:middle">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```